# Storage Bench Possible with 3/4" Plywood/MDF?

Tags: wood, woodworking, wooden-furniture

Is it possible to make the storage bench below using only wood glue, screws, and 3/4-inch plywood or MDF?

The only requirement is that it must support a 80lb kid sitting on it.  4.5" floor clearance is a must.  I don't think it would be strong enough (diagram is to scale).  Any ideas to make it stronger are much appreciated.  I'm in a remote area with limited tools (saw, drill, screws, glue, and 1 trip to home center)

[image]

Comment: I would put a back on the bench as well as maybe a center divider to help with the weight.

Comment: Consider adding a 2x2 or 1x4 as a beam under the main bench. That will help to reinforce the parallelogram (easiest mode for lateral collapse) as well as the bending of the top MDF board (flexural failure mode).

Comment: Thanks guys, very helpful.  Flexural failure was fun reading up on.  I know there's a right way to do this with thicker wood but I'm intentionally taking shortcuts for time's sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **ideas to make it stronger**

#### Resisting vertical forces

Add a rail front and rear, inset from front and rear edges. The rail would be 31" wide x 2" high. Make it taller for greater strength.

#### Resisting lateral forces

The greatest weakness is lateral collapse by lozenging. Adding metal corner brackets or adding a back panel would prevent that. With an inset back panel you wouldn't need a rear rail.

Minimum would be an unobtrusive triangular wooden brace centrally at each end of the underside of the top, glued with tenons or plenty of dowels.

Comment: Out of technical curiosity, how could this design be achieved without back panel or rails? Thicker wood and stronger joins? eg https://goo.gl/KfLVBk

Comment: @Chris: Thicker wood, stronger wood species, wood with fewer knots, steel corner braces, smaller span, lighter children, planet with lower mass, ...